# How to host content externally on Parse?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, in-app-purchase

I want to pack a lot of products into one for Black Friday.

The upload limit @ Parse is 10 MB and I need to upload 145 MB. How can I re-route a download to an external hosted content without releasing a new version of my app?

I Hope you can Answer this soon.
It's really important for us to put this Black Friday offer in place.

EDIT:

OK, now I Know I'll Need to Update my App to Download the Content externally. Does Anyone have the Code on how to Download the Content From an External Host Instead of Parse once the Purchase is Approved? THANKS

What I'm Doing now is:

// FOR THE PURCHASE:

```
    [PFPurchase buyProduct:<ProductID>  block:^(NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // run UI logic that informs user the product has been purchased, such as displaying an alert view.
            [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Downloading..."];
        }else
        {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
            [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Error"];
        }
}];

// AND EARLIER....
// adding the Purchase Observer

[PFPurchase addObserverForProduct:<ProductID> block:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction) {
        [PFPurchase downloadAssetForTransaction:transaction    completion:^(NSString *filePath, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                // Unzipping
         //...... AND SAVING THE FILES, ETC.....
       }
```

}];

// Thanks Stack-Overflowers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your App is actually getting the images out of Parse, then you are stuck with the 10 MB limit unfortunately.  In order to get around that you would need to store the URL to the image in Parse and host the image somewhere else.  Unfortunately you would need to modify your App in the code to handle the URL which will require another release.

It seems like the only thing you can do at this point is to reduce the quality or dimensions of your images to shrink the file size to < 10 MB.

Comment: Thanks @dstudeba. Well, Actually Its a .ZIP File we are talking about, and Its Full of already compressed sounds. I Guess I'll have to Find a Work-Around for this... thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Hey Hernan. I've dealt with this in the past, and ended up storing the 'product' in parse so the purchase goes through like normal, but then having the URL pull from something like AWS's S3 - if you've never used it before it's one of the easiest file storage systems ever.

Comment: Yes, @d3fau17, good point.  One of the reasons it is nice to store URLs outside of the iOS App is that you can modify them without having to resubmit and go through the approval.  (of course you need them to be https now)

Comment: S3 auto servers over https =] also, you can easily set up access for it, and you can also route it through a nice DNS service like cloudflare or Route53 so you get free CDN (with cloudflare) and you can change the endpoints using page rules if you have to.